# Sort Arrays of a Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below:

```
my_dict = {'A': [5, 2, 1, 6], 'B': [7, 10, 18, 11]}
```

I want to change it to the following:

```
my_dict = {'A': [1, 2, 5, 6], 'B': [7, 10, 11, 18]}
```

How Can I sort the arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **iterate** on the **dictionary keys** and **sort** each array using `sorted()`:

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
    my_dict[key] = sorted(my_dict[key])
```

my_dict is now:

```
{'A': [1, 2, 5, 6], 'B': [7, 10, 11, 18]}
```

As mentioned by [@Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen), it is more efficient to sort in place:

```
for value in my_dict.values():
    value.sort()
```